# Plotting a Pandas DataFrame of Char Data using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The data in the dataset is comprised purely of chars. For example:

```
p,x,s,n,t,p,f,c,n,k,e,e,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,k,s,u
e,x,s,y,t,a,f,c,b,k,e,c,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,n,n,g
e,b,s,w,t,l,f,c,b,n,e,c,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,n,n,m
p,x,y,w,t,p,f,c,n,n,e,e,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,k,s,u
e,x,s,g,f,n,f,w,b,k,t,e,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,e,n,a,g
```

A complete copy of the data can be found in [agaricus-lepiota.data in the uci machine learning datasets mushroom dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/mushroom/)

Are there methods of visualisation for using char data (instead of having to convert the data set to numeric) via matplotlib?

Just for any sort of visualization i.e:

```
filename = 'mushrooms.csv'
df_mushrooms = pd.read_csv(filename, names = ["Classes", "Cap-Shape", "Cap-Surface", "Cap-Colour", "Bruises", "Odor", "Gill-Attachment", "Gill-Spacing", "Gill-Size", "Gill-Colour", "Stalk-Shape", "Stalk-Root", "Stalk-Surface-Above-Ring", "Stalk-Surface-Below-Ring", "Stalk-Colour-Above-Ring", "Stalk-Colour-Below-Ring", "Veil-Type", "Veil-Colour", "Ring-Number", "Ring-Type", "Spore-Print-Colour", "Population", "Habitat"])


#If there are any entires (rows) with any missing values/NaN's drop the row.
df_mushrooms.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'any', inplace = True)

df_mushrooms.plot.scatter(x = 'Classes', y = 'Cap-Shape')
```

Comment: I don't think so. It's a big question on what the characters represent. Fortunately, converting to numbers is easy.

Comment: There's a `pd.factorize` method you can use. Alternatively, convert to categorical.

Comment: In principle you can do something like `plt.scatter(["e","w","a","e"], ["z","t","z","u"])`. Not sure if this is what you're after, especially since in the mushroom case what would be the information conveyed by such plot? Wouldn't you rather want to know how many brown mushrooms are edible or such things where the quantity is of interest? A scatter would only show a dot, no matter how often that combination is in the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do this, but with this approach it doesn't really make any sense from a graphical point of view. If you were to do what you asked for it would look like this:

[image]

And I know I shouldn't tread into the territory of telling someone how to present their graphs, but this doesn't convey any information to me. The issue is that using `Classes` and `Cap-Shape` fields for your `x` and `y` indices will always put the same letter in the same place. There is no variability. Perhaps there is some other field you could use as the index and then use the `Cap-Shape` as your marker, but as it is this doesn't add any value. Again that is to me personally.

To use a string as a marker you can use the "$...$" marker described in [`matplotlib.markers`](https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html#matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle), but again I must provide the caveat that graphing like this is much slower than the traditional method as you must iterate over the rows of your dataframe.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# Classes only has 'p' and 'e' as unique values so we will map them as 1 and 2 on the index
df['Class_Id'] = df.Classes.map(lambda x: 1 if x == 'p' else 2)
df['Cap_Val'] = df['Cap-Shape'].map(lambda x: ord(x) - 96)
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    ax.scatter(x=row.Class_Id, y=row.Cap_Val, marker=r"$ {} $".format(row['Cap-Shape']), c=plt.cm.nipy_spectral(row.Cap_Val / 26))
ax.set_xticks([0,1,2,3])
ax.set_xticklabels(['', 'p', 'e', ''])
ax.set_yticklabels(['', 'e', 'j', 'o', 't', 'y'])
fig.show()
```